# Python - Find suffixes that commonly occur in one list, but not in another

Tags: python

I have a 3 lists of words. One list only contains words in the Afrikaans language. One list only contains words in the English language. The third list contains words in both languages. I am trying to automatically determine which words in the third list belong in which of the first two lists. One way I thought of was to look at the longest common substring occurring at the end.

So for example, words in English would end in ..tic, whereas words in Afrikaans would end in ..ties (example alphabetic vs alfabeties).

How can I automatically find suffixes that commonly occur in the first list, but not in the second list? I would like to use Python for this. I use Python lists for the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a fixed suffix size `suffix_size` and a threshold for "commonly" `thresh`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def suffix_counts(wordlist):
    output = defaultdict(int)
    counts =  Counter(
        word[-suffix_size:]
        for word in wordlist
        if len(word) >= suffix_size
    )
    output.update(counts)
    return output

afrikaans_suffixes = suffix_counts(afrikaans_list)
english_suffixes = suffix_counts(english_list)
common_english_suffixes = [
    suffix
    for suffix, count in english_suffixes.iteritems()
    if (float(count) / (count + afrikaans_suffixes[suffix])) > thresh
]  # All suffixes which are found in English thresh percent of the time
```

That having been said, this is likely not to be the best approach for this problem - you might find it worthwhile to look into constructing n-gram models for each language using something like nltk, then classifying your unknown words using these models.

Comment: Used thresh = 2 and suffix_size = 3 and got an empty list for common_english_suffixes

Comment: Values of thresh less than 1 returns values, but not anything that makes sense to me

Comment: Sorry, should have specified - thresh should be between .5 and 1, with .5 meaning "found equally in Afrikaans and English" and 1 meaning "found exclusively in English". For the following:
    `thresh = .75`
    `suffix_size = 3`
    `afrikaans_list = ['xties', 'yties', 'zties', 'aties', 'btic']`
    `english_list = ['xtic', 'ytic', 'ztic', 'atic', 'bties']`,

`common_english_suffixes` is `['tic']`.